# Changes to document are not saved

Tags: document-library

I have a document library in which I store Excel documents to gather feedback from users.

Lately when documents are edited, changes are not visible.

Any ideas why?

Comment: The most common problem is that users open excel via Firefox or Chrome and this browsers download excel locally to the computer. Try using Internet Explorer which opens Excel in SP and does not save file locally.

Comment: I think my users only use IE as browser. Firefox is not in the company computers and they are instructed to use only IE. But I'll keep in mind your advice. Thanks!